# How to use sherlock action bar on 2.x android version

Tags: android, resources, actionbarsherlock, android-2.2-froyo

I want to use Sherlock Action Bar on android 2.x. But i have some errors, like

```
android-apt-compiler: [actionbarsherlock] .../projects/...libs/actionbarsherlock    /res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
```

How can I use the library on android 2.x? 
Thx

**Edit**
In styles.xml in my project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
</resources>
```

In abs__styles.xml in library module (values-v14)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabText" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionButton" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.CloseMode" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionButton.Overflow" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionMode" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionMode">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionMode" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionMode.Inverse" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.PopupMenu">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Spinner">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListView.DropDown" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.PopupWindow.ActionMode" parent="android:Widget.Holo.PopupWindow">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.PopupWindow.ActionMode" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupWindow">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar.Horizontal" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.SearchAutoCompleteTextView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.AutoCompleteTextView">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.SearchAutoCompleteTextView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse">
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Title" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title">
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse">
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle">
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse">
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu">
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu.Large" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu.Small" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
</style>
</resources>
```

In library module in values/abs__styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
<style name="Widget">
</style>

<style name="Sherlock.__Widget.ActionBar" parent="Widget">
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item>
    <item name="height">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dip</item>
    <item name="homeLayout">@layout/abs__action_bar_home</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/abs__ab_transparent_dark_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/abs__ab_stacked_transparent_dark_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/abs__ab_bottom_transparent_dark_holo</item>
    <item name="divider">?attr/dividerVertical</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
    <item name="indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar</item>
    <item name="progressBarPadding">32dip</item>
    <item name="itemPadding">8dip</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/abs__ab_solid_dark_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/abs__ab_stacked_solid_dark_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/abs__ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo</item>
    <item name="divider">?attr/dividerVertical</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
    <item name="indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar</item>
    <item name="progressBarPadding">32dip</item>
    <item name="itemPadding">8dip</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/abs__ab_transparent_light_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/abs__ab_stacked_transparent_light_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/abs__ab_bottom_transparent_light_holo</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_holo_light</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
    <item name="indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ProgressBar</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/abs__ab_solid_light_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/abs__ab_stacked_solid_light_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/abs__ab_bottom_solid_light_holo</item>
    <item name="divider">?attr/dividerVertical</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
    <item name="indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ProgressBar</item>
    <item name="progressBarPadding">32dip</item>
    <item name="itemPadding">8dip</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/abs__ab_solid_dark_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/abs__ab_stacked_solid_dark_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/abs__ab_bottom_solid_inverse_holo</item>
    <item name="divider">@drawable/abs__list_divider_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
    <item name="indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar</item>
    <item name="progressBarPadding">32dip</item>
    <item name="itemPadding">8dip</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abs__tab_indicator_ab_holo</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:divider">?attr/actionBarDivider</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">12dip</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabText" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">?attr/actionBarSize</item>

    <item name="android:minWidth">@dimen/abs__action_button_min_width</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">12dip</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionButton" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abs__btn_cab_done_holo_dark</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abs__btn_cab_done_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/abs__action_menu_overflow_description</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="Sherlock.__Widget.ActionMode" parent="Widget">
    <item name="background">?attr/actionModeBackground</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">?attr/actionModeSplitBackground</item>
    <item name="height">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionMode" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.ActionMode">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Title</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionMode" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionMode">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Title</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionMode.Inverse" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.ActionMode">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse</item>
</style>


<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/abs__menu_dropdown_panel_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/abs__menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.PopupMenu" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.PopupMenu" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow">
</style>


<style name="Sherlock.__Widget.ActivityChooserView" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abs__ab_share_pack_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:divider">?attr/dividerVertical</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">6dip</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActivityChooserView" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.ActivityChooserView">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActivityChooserView" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActivityChooserView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abs__ab_share_pack_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Button.Small" parent="Widget">
  <item name="android:textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_dark</item>
  <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
  <item name="android:minWidth">48dip</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.Button.Small" parent="Widget">
  <item name="android:textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_light</item>
  <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
  <item name="android:minWidth">48dip</item>
</style>


<style name="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.Spinner" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/abs__menu_dropdown_panel_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abs__spinner_ab_holo_dark</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abs__spinner_ab_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/abs__menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.ListView" parent="android:Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/abs__list_divider_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_dark</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.ListView">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListView.DropDown" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.ListView">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/abs__list_divider_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.DropDownItem" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.DropDownItem</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.DropDownItem.Spinner" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.DropDownItem">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.DropDownItem">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.PopupWindow.ActionMode" parent="Widget">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.PopupWindow.ActionMode" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>



<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/abs__progress_medium_holo</item>
    <item name="android:animationResolution">33</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ProgressBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar">
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar.Horizontal" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/abs__progress_horizontal_holo_dark</item>
    <!--item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/abs__progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo</item-->
    <item name="android:minHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">16dip</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/abs__progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
</style>



<style name="Widget.Sherlock.TextView.SpinnerItem" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
</style>



<style name="Sherlock.__Widget.SearchAutoCompleteTextView" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:completionHintView">@layout/abs__simple_dropdown_hint</item>
    <item name="android:completionThreshold">2</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.SearchAutoCompleteTextView"  parent="Sherlock.__Widget.SearchAutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_dark</item>
      <item     name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/abs__menu_dropdown_panel_holo_dark</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.SearchAutoCompleteTextView" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.SearchAutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/abs__menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light</item>
</style>



<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/actionMenuTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">@bool/abs__config_actionMenuItemAllCaps</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abs__action_bar_title_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abs__action_bar_title_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abs__action_bar_subtitle_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abs__action_bar_subtitle_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Title" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abs__action_bar_title_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abs__action_bar_title_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abs__action_bar_subtitle_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abs__action_bar_subtitle_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.DropDownItem" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorPrimaryDisableOnly</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

<style name="Sherlock.__TextAppearance.Small" parent="Widget">
  <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Small" parent="Sherlock.__TextAppearance.Small">
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Light.Small"     parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Small">
</style>
```

..................

Comment: what sdk version do you use?

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

Comment: is sdk v15 assigned to project? Go to project android properties and look

Comment: Project sdk set to Android 2.3.3

Comment: that is your problem. You should to use sdk 4.1 or 4.2

Comment: I need to use my project on devices with Android 2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `parent="Theme.Sherlock"` as parent. 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar' is up to Android 3.0

you have to use the `Widget.Sherlock` as parent for your style

Comment: In what file should i use <style name="android:Widger.Holo.ActionBar" parent="Theme.Sherlock"/>??

Comment: use this way: <style name="MyActionBarStyleName" parent="Theme.Sherlock"/> and reference it as @style/MyActionBarStyleName

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand) I have 'values' folder into library, styles.xml with errors. Where i should change style?

Comment: did you change the name attribute ?

Comment: No, not yet changed. Because i don't know where i should change. <style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar"> replace this to...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31206/discussion-between-yuriy-aizenberg-and-blackbelt)

Answer (score 1):

Update your project SDK to 4.1 or 4.2

Comment: I need to use my project on devices with Android 2.2

Comment: that doesn't matter. For that option you have minSdkVersion parameter

Comment: I'm on 4.3 and that doesn't help.